# What happens to Salesforce OAuth tokens when a user blocks your app or revokes access

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, rest

I have a non-Apex app that relies on OAuth only. I'm trying to test out what happens if the user revokes access or blocks the app and/or then unblocks the app. In my limited testing, it seems that I always have to reauthenticate the user and get new tokens. Is that always true for all of these events? Are there any events wherein the app can re-use the tokens if the user gives my app access again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If OAuth token is revoked then there is no way to re-use old token. We need to re-issue OAuth token again.

Comment: That makes sense for the revoke case. What about blocking and unblocking? Is the OAuth token invalidated during that process?

Comment: Even in case Block/Unblock we need to issue new OAuth token. You can try thus - Navigate to "https://aside.io" Authorize this app. Then block it. Now, Unblock. Application would prompt again to authorize.